# Wrong stamp in my passport!

Tags: united-kingdom, passport, new-zealand

I travel on a NZ passport and have lived in the UK since 2006. I travelled to Canada in June 2016 to begin a 2 year Canadian working visa but on a trip back to the UK in July I received a 6 month visa stamp in my passport despite having an Indefinite Leave To Remain Visa in my old passport (I haven't got a biometric card yet but plan to apply for one while in Canada before I return to the UK to live.

What should I do about this?[image]

Comment: Did you show the old passport and its ILR sticker to the immigration officer?  Was the ILR sticker expired?

Comment: Question originally appeared at https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103473/immigration-officer-placed-a-standard-leave-to-enter-stamp-when-i-have-indefinit (closed now, has some discussion already)